# Duplicate Key Error in SQL and Delete and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, on-duplicate-key

I need to insert rows from select, if key is duplicate then delete entry and insert them

```
 Table1 

  ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  ColumnD
   A          1        A1        7/21/2017
   B          2        B1        7/22/2017
   C           3       C1       7/23/2017
```

Unique Combination ColumnA and ColumnC

```
 Table2

  ColumnE  ColumnF ColumnG
    A        1      A1
    A         2     A2
    B         3     B1
    B         2     B2
    C         3     C1
    C         1     C2
```

I should insert the rows from table 2 to table 1

```
Insert into table1 (columnA, columnB, ColumnC) select columnE, ColumnF, ColumnG from table2
```

The above query gets conflicts saying duplicate keys are inserted but want 
  a way to delete rows which creates conflicts and insert that row.
  final output should be

```
 Table 1
 ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC  ColumnD  
    A        1      A1     08/08/2017  - deleted and added as conflict arised
    A         2     A2     08/08/2017
    B         3     B1     08/08/2017  -deleted and added as conflict arised
    B         2     B2     08/08/2017
    C         3     C1     08/08/2017    
    C         1     C2     08/08/2017
```

Comment: `MERGE`. `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`.

Comment: Can you please provide some specific example for this case?

Comment: Merge is still unfortunately slow. a DI (Delete, then Insert) sequence will probably be better, although a UI (update, then insert) sequence would be best.

Comment: What is the column D in table 1? How do you determine the date?

Comment: I assumed that was a column with a default value.

Comment: @MislavZic ColumnD is the date when record is inserted

Comment: @LaughingVergil There is no UI interface to it, standalone stored procedure

Comment: @LaughingVergil was using the acronym "UI" to mean "Update/Insert", not User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete then insert. Just update the `ColumnD` column (or all non-key columns) and insert new ones from the `Table2`. I would order statements so that firstly goes `UPDATE` and then `INSERT`, so that the `UPDATE` works on smaller set of original rows (before the insert). Here it is, instead of `MERGE`, just plain old `UPDATE-INSERT`:

```
DECLARE
    @Conflicted TABLE(
        ColumnA char(1),
        ColumnB int,
        ColumnC char(2),
        ColumnD date
    )

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE dst
SET
    dst.ColumnD = GETDATE()
OUTPUT
    deleted.ColumnA,
    deleted.ColumnB,
    deleted.ColumnC,
    deleted.ColumnD
INTO
    @Conflicted
FROM
    Table1 AS dst
    JOIN Table2 AS src
    ON dst.ColumnA = src.ColumnE AND
       dst.ColumnB = src.ColumnF AND
       dst.ColumnC = src.ColumnG

INSERT INTO Table1(
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC,
    ColumnD
)
SELECT
    t2.ColumnE,
    t2.ColumnF,
    t2.ColumnG,
    GETDATE()
FROM
    Table2 AS t2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnA = t2.ColumnE AND ColumnB = t2.ColumnF AND ColumnC = t2.ColumnG)

COMMIT TRAN
```

In the table variable `@Conflicted` now you have all conflicted rows from the `Table1` which have been replaced with new ones from the `Table2`.

And here is a version with `MERGE`:

```
DECLARE
    @Updated TABLE(
        ColumnA char(1),
        ColumnB int,
        ColumnC char(2),
        ColumnD date,
        Action nvarchar(10)
    )

MERGE Table1 AS dst
USING (
    SELECT * FROM Table2
) as src
ON dst.ColumnA = src.ColumnE AND
   dst.ColumnB = src.ColumnF AND
   dst.ColumnC = src.ColumnG
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT(
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC,
        ColumnD
    ) VALUES (
        src.ColumnE,
        src.ColumnF,
        src.ColumnG,
        GETDATE()
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
        dst.ColumnD = GETDATE()
OUTPUT
    deleted.ColumnA,
    deleted.ColumnB,
    deleted.ColumnC,
    deleted.ColumnD,
    $action AS action
INTO
    @Updated;

SELECT * FROM @Updated WHERE Action = 'UPDATE' -- List replaced rows from the Table1
```